# "The Sergeant over there's wife" is correct?

Tags: apostrophe

The sentence below is a line from the movie Inglorious Basterds.

> **The Sergeant over there's wife** just had a baby.

Is the use of the apostrophe correct?
 As this is almost my first time seeing an apostrophe placed after such a phrase which consists of a noun and then adverbs, I am not sure of that.

Any explanation will be appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possessive apostrophe-s attaches to the end of the noun phrase, not just the head noun. The noun phrase here is 'the Sergeant over there'. This sentence is correct but awkward.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Sydney. But may I ask you to explain a bit more about why it sounds **awkward** despite that it is correct? If it is not a good expression, then how can it be corrected? Is ***The wife of the Sergeant over there just had a baby*** correct?

Comment: It sounds awkward because the apostrophe-s which *should* be attached to 'Sergeant' (because it's the sergeant's wife) is instead attached to something else. Yes, it is almost always possible and almost always less awkward to reword using 'of'.

Comment: Thank you for the continuous help. It has been a wonderful help.